# Python pass constant arguments to base class

Tags: python, templates, generics, inheritance, abstraction

Q. How should I pass ***constant*** arguments to a a Python base class?

Using the typical example, I have classes `Cat` and `Dog` (both derived from `Animal`).
Calling `x.sound` should return the appropriate word (`"meow"`, `"woof"`).

My issue is that all instances of the class make the same sound, and therefore while I can pass a `sound` to `Animal`:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__( sound ):
        self.sound = sound

class Dog:
    def __init__():
        super().__init__( "woof" )
```

This seems wasteful, since we store `"woof"` in every instance and I have a million dogs and a billion cats. I could use a method instead then:

```
class Animal:
    @staticmethod
    def sound():
        raise NotImplementedError("Abstract")

class Dog:
    @staticmethod
    def sound():
        return "woof"
```

But now, since my animals are all very quiet, this is easily missed when someone else comes along and writes a `Bird` class without reading my painstakingly written documentation, and only discovers they forgot the method once in a blue moon when the method's actually called.

Ideally I'd like something like C++'s templates, where the `Animal` class itself takes the parameter - it can't be missed without causing an immediate error, and doesn't take up any more space per instance.

```
template<sound>
class Animal()
    . . .
```

Is there way of accomplishing what I'm after in Python?

Comment: I think all the dog instances should receive the same actual string object due to string interning.

Comment: i am not very sure but you might need `__slots__` for this

Comment: @PaulRooney still got a pointer for every object then. Also, the pointer to the interned string will be 8 bytes on a 64-bit system, that's longer than the "woof" string itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a factory design pattern. Something like this:

```
class AnimalFactory(object):
    animals={}

    @staticmethod
    def registerAnimal(animalName, animalClass):
        if not hasattr(animalClass, "sound"):
            raise Exception("All animals need to make a sound")
        AnimalFactory.animals[animalName]=animalClass

    @staticmethod
    def createNewAnimal(animalName):
        return AnimalFactory.animals[animalName]()

class Dog:
    sound="woof"

AnimalFactory.registerAnimal("dog", Dog)

dog1=AnimalFactory.createNewAnimal("dog")
print dog1.sound

class Cat:
    pass

AnimalFactory.registerAnimal("cat", Cat)
```

The above code produces the following output

```
woof
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "animals.py", line 25, in <module>
    AnimalFactory.registerAnimal("cat", Cat)
  File "animals.py", line 7, in registerAnimal
    raise Exception("All animals need to make a sound")
```

Of course, a user may forget to register a class, but as long as other users use `AnimalFactory` to create a new animal, this should work ok.